# how to avoid switch-case

Tags: c#

How can I refactor this code to avoid switch-cases? Is there a way of changing commands without adding new case and make it dynamically...I want the solution not to depend on the amount of cases. For example, if I have 1000 commands..I should obviously write them all as cases?
I hope my problem is clear.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ConsoleHelp ch1 = new ConsoleHelp();
    Plus pl = new Plus();
    Minus mn = new Minus();
    Divide dv = new Divide();
    Multiply mlt = new Multiply();
    Sinus sin = new Sinus();
    Tangent tan = new Tangent();
    Square sq = new Square();
    Degree dg = new Degree();
    Percent pr = new Percent();

    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("command> ");
        string com = Console.ReadLine();
        if (com != null)
        {
            switch (com.ToLower())
            {
                case "?":
                    ch1.Helpper();
                    break;
                case "plus":
                    pl.Sum();
                    break;
                case "minus":
                    mn.Minusvalue();
                    break;
                case "divide":
                    dv.Dividevalue();
                    break;
                case "multiply":
                    mlt.Multvalue();
                    break;
                case "sinus":
                    sin.Sinusvalue();
                    break;
                case "tangent":
                    tan.Tangentvalue();
                    break;
                case "square":
                    sq.Squarevalue();
                    break;
                case "degree":
                    dg.Degvalue();
                    break;
                case "percent":
                    pr.Pervalue();
                    break;
                case "c":
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("The command is not supported. Enter one of the valid commands.");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Not sure what the classes do but you could register all the functions in a dictionary<string, object> and simply call _action[com.ToLower()].Execute() (Make all your actions implement an interface that has Execute method).

Answer (score 7):

You can create your own Attribute to decorate all of your classes (e.g., Plus, ConsoleHelp, Minus, Divide, and even Exit).  In the sample below, the attribute is called `SystemCommandAttribute`.  It would require to specify what the name of the command would be as a constructor parameter (what the user would have to type on the command line).

The next step would be to have each of your command classes implement the same interface.  In the example code I used the name `ISystemCommand`.  That interface should have a single method:  `Execute()`.  That way we know what to call when we want to invoke the command.

Then you can use reflection to search for all classes that have that attribute and load them into a dictionary of `string` to `ISystemCommand`.  The `GetCommandsFromAssemblies()` method handles instantiating each instance of `ISystemCommand` for you.

From there you can use the dictionary instead of the switch statement.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, ISystemCommand> commandToType = GetCommandsFromAssemblies();
        RunCommandLoop(commandToType);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Loop over all types currently loaded in the AppDomain looking for ISystemCommand
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A dictionary from command name to instance of command</returns>
    private static Dictionary<string, ISystemCommand> GetCommandsFromAssemblies()
    {
        var typesWithMyAttribute =
            from a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            from t in a.GetTypes()
            let attributes = t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SystemCommandAttribute), true)
            where attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0
            select new
            {
                Instance = (ISystemCommand)Activator.CreateInstance(t),
                CommandName = attributes.Cast<SystemCommandAttribute>().Single().CommandName
            };

        Dictionary<string, ISystemCommand> commandToType = typesWithMyAttribute.ToDictionary(t => t.CommandName, t => t.Instance);

        return commandToType;
    }

    private static void RunCommandLoop(Dictionary<string, ISystemCommand> actions)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("command> ");
            string com = Console.ReadLine();
            if (com != null)
            {
                ISystemCommand action;

                if (actions.TryGetValue(com, out action))
                {
                    action.Execute();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The command is not supported. Enter one of the valid commands.");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public interface ISystemCommand
{
    void Execute();
}

public class SystemCommandAttribute : Attribute
{
    public SystemCommandAttribute(string commandName)
    {
        CommandName = commandName;
    }

    public string CommandName { get; set; }
}

[SystemCommand("plus")]
public class Plus : ISystemCommand
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        Sum();
    }

    private void Sum()
    {
        // your existing Sum logic here
        Console.WriteLine("Sum called");
    }
}


[SystemCommand("?")]
public class ConsoleHelp : ISystemCommand
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        Helper();
    }

    private void Helper()
    {
        // your existing Helper logic here
        Console.WriteLine("Helper called");
    }
}

[SystemCommand("c")]
public class ExitCommand : ISystemCommand
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

To add a new command in the future, all you would need to do would be to

1. create your command class
2. Inherit from ISystmeCommand
3. Add the SystmCommandAttribute

Your main program would not need to change at all.

Comment: Instead of `First()`, I prefer to use `Single()` most of the time, to make sure accidental duplicate errors are caught early. And using similar logic, it's better to use `Cast()` instead of `OfType()`.

Comment: good point @svick.  I've updated the sample to use `Single()` and `Cast()`

Comment: There is also an important restriction: command classes should implement a default constructor (probably there should be a custom exception thrown?). This, ofc, can be avoided by using a dependency injection.

Comment: Also, in case it's not obvious, this suggestion is an implementation of the Command Pattern - http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternCommand.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ConsoleHelp ch1 = new ConsoleHelp();
    Plus pl = new Plus();
    Minus mn = new Minus();
    Divide dv = new Divide();
    Multiply mlt = new Multiply();
    Sinus sin = new Sinus();
    Tangent tan = new Tangent();
    Square sq = new Square();
    Degree dg = new Degree();
    Percent pr = new Percent();
    System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, Action> actions = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, Action>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    {
        { "?", ch1.Helpper },
        { "plus", pl.Sum },
        { "minus", mn.Minusvalue },
        { "divide", dv.Dividevalue },
        { "multiply", mlt.Multvalue },
        { "sinus", sin.Sinusvalue },
        { "tangent", tan.Tangentvalue },
        { "square", sq.Squarevalue },
        { "degree", dg.Degvalue },
        { "percent", pr.Pervalue },
        { "c", Exit },
    };

    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("command> ");
        string com = Console.ReadLine();
        if (com != null)
        {
            Action action;

            if (actions.TryGetValue(com, out action))
            {
                action.Invoke();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The command is not supported. Enter one of the valid commands.");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void Exit()
{
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Comment: This being a strict answer to your question - removing the `switch` - there are much better, more object-oriented ways to accomplish what I think you want. Seeing the operations classes (such as `Plus`) would help to refactor into something much more maintainable and extensible.

Comment: You could simplify this even more by inlining all those  locals: `{ "?", new ConsoleHelp().Helpper }, { "plus", new Plus().Sum }, …`.

Comment: This answer is bad prctice, imho. It does not really solve the problem. Instead of writing 1000 `case` statements you will hardcode a 1000-element `Dictionary`, which is essentially the same thing (and the same source of errors, typos, etc). When it comes to classes, it is almost always possible to extract a common interface/baseclass to avoid, and that is what should be used (as already suggested by Josh).

Comment: Hence, my very first comment.